# Why isn't iTunes Radio presenting the options affecting station variety?

Tags: itunes, itunes-radio

I am not seeing the options in iTunes Radio for "Play More Like This" and "Never Play This" for individual songs, nor the "Variety" slider for each station.

[image: Add to iTunes Wish List]

[image: iTunes Radio]

Per iTunes Help docs:

> While a song is playing, click [image] near the top-left of the iTunes window, and choose Play More Like This or Never Play This Song from the pop-up menu.
>
> Adjust the balance between new and familiar songs (on the selected station only): Click a station to display its contents, and click Hits (familiar), Variety (mixed), or Discovery (new).

These features are consistently missing across all of dozens of songs on multiple stations. I can't find anything in the Preferences (or the View, Window, or contextual menus) that seems relevant, except perhaps that I have "Share details about your library" turned off. Is it related? I tried turning it on and see no change.

An interesting twist is that I created a station **on iOS 7**, using an identical starting condition - the name of a band - to one of my existing stations, which has now synced to my OS X iTunes radio, and *includes* these options. The stations created on OS X have not transferred to the iDevice, however.

<sup>1<sup>st</sup></sup> Created on iOS, appeared on OS X.
<sup>2<sup>nd</sup></sup> Created on OS X, not present on iOS.

[image: Created on iOS - appeared on OS X]
[image: Created on OS X - not present on iOS]

Why can't I tell iTunes that I don't ever want to hear "Margaritaville"?!

This is iTunes 11.1 (126) running on OS X 10.8.4

Comment: This has now started working as expected -- new stations created on OS X have these options and sync to iOS. First-day glitches, I guess.

Comment: I have the same issue but on iOS: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102685/why-cant-i-vote-on-itunes-radio-songs?noredirect=1#comment120847_102685

Comment: As answered by @SteveMoser, it seems you added the DJ curated station to your own station. You can’t adjust your song preferences with it. The only way to enable that option is by creating an entirely new personalized station.

Answer (score 2):

It only works if you add your own custom stations. When you are listening to a song that you like, press on start station from artist or song. Then that new station will have the options on: play more like this, or never play this song. :)

Answer (score 1):

According the [Apple support doc](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5848) for iTunes Radio:

> There may be some DJ-curated stations that you may not be able to
>   modify. You can't like or play more tracks like this while listening
>   to some DJ-curated stations. You can however, start new stations based
>   on the current track or artist of a featured station or add tracks to
>   your iTunes Wishlist from the Star (✭) menu.

As for the slider you can only use it on non-DJ-curated stations. Create a station from an artist or song then you will see the slider.

Comment: This isn't it in my case, unfortunately, though it might be for other people. These stations were created from an artist name (in one case, an album name). Now, however, identically-created stations _are_ showing the options. It seems to have just been a glitch.