# Why can't I vote on iTunes Radio songs?

Tags: ios, itunes-radio

The like and dislike options are grayed out. I'm on an iPhone 5s and iOS 7.0.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible for you give us but more information to prevent wild guessing. For example, what have you tried, are you logged in iTunes, what OS? what device ? You have 2k points, you should know how to ask a question.

Comment: @Buscar웃 updated question. Also it looks like this is related. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102435/why-isnt-itunes-radio-presenting-the-options-affecting-station-variety

Comment: You might have to reinstall the remote and reestablish the connections to you DJ stations, assuming thy did not block you.

Comment: @Buscar웃 What do you mean by 'reinstall the remote'?

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH1741

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the [Apple support doc](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5848) for iTunes Radio:

> There may be some DJ-curated stations that you may not be able to
>   modify. You can't like or play more tracks like this while listening
>   to some DJ-curated stations. You can however, start new stations based
>   on the current track or artist of a featured station or add tracks to
>   your iTunes Wishlist from the Star (✭) menu.